# Emacs 25.2 dired mode shows .. above . How do I change this?

Tags: windows, emacs, dired

On my win-10 machine, dired shows this:

```
    drwxr-xr-x 58 jkb jkb     4096 Nov  5 11:08 ..
    drwxr-xr-x  6 jkb jkb     4096 Nov  6 09:34 .
```

Where the .. entry comes first. How do I modify the installation to change it back to this:

```
    drwxr-xr-x  6 jkb jkb     4096 Nov  6 09:34 .
    drwxr-xr-x 58 jkb jkb     4096 Nov  5 11:08 ..
```

It is not a big issue, except that on my mint 18 machine it shows the traditional order. Uniformity would be good.

Many thanks for pointers and advice.

[See the first comment to this question for the answer]

Comment: I think Emacs uses the `ls-lisp` library on Windows to substitute for the lack of a native `ls`.  Have a look around in `M-x customize-group RET ls-lisp RET` on your Windows installation.

Comment: Are you using `helm-dired`?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to ls-lisp.  Setting ls-lisp-UCA-like-collation to nil solved the issue.  There is a side-effect for the ordering of the ~/.* files in the cygwin home directory but I am fairly sure I can manage with that ok.

Comment: @JohnBeattie You should post an answer and accept it whenever SO allows you to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formal answer:

I can solve my issue by setting ls-lisp-UCA-like-collation to nil:

```
    '(ls-list-UCA-like-collation nil)
```

in the customize section of my .emacs file or via the customize menus.

The change has the side-effect of changing the ordering of the cygwin home directory, the ~/.* files come first now.

There may be another option to fix that, if it is important.

Note that this is an issue with dired on emacs, using ls-lisp.